# Is it inequality true

Tags: inequality, radicals, nested-radicals, number-comparison, jensen-inequality

Please help me prove the inequality:

$$\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt[3] 3}+\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt[3] 3}<2\sqrt[3] 3$$

Thanky for your help and your attention.

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be
$$a=\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt[3] 3}, b=\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt[3] 3}$$
now we have
$$a^3+b^3=\left(\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt[3] 3}\right)^3+\left(\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt[3] 3}\right)^3=3+\sqrt[3]3+3-\sqrt[3]3=6.$$
Becouese,
$$a^3+b^3>a^2b+b^2a$$
we have
$$ab(a+b)<a^3+b^3=6$$
Now
$$3ab(a+b)<18$$
or
$$3a^2b+3ab^2<18$$
Add in the both sides eqution:
$$a^3+b^3=6$$
and inequality
$$3a^2b+3ab^2<18$$
we have:
$$(a+b)^3<24=8\cdot 3$$
or
$$a+b<2\sqrt[3]3$$

Answer (score 2):

Also your inequality it's just Jensen for $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x$.

Indeed, $f$ is a concave function.

Since your inequality it's 
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt[3] 3}+\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt[3] 3}}{2}<\sqrt[3]{\frac{3+\sqrt[3] 3+3-\sqrt[3] 3}{2}}$$
we are done!

Answer (score 1):

We can use $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)$.

Since $a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc=0\Leftrightarrow a=b=c$

and $\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt[3]3}\neq\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt[3]3}$ , we need to prove that
$$3+\sqrt[3]3+3-\sqrt[3]3-8\cdot3+3\cdot2\sqrt[3]3\sqrt[3]{9-\sqrt[3]9}<0$$ or
$$\sqrt[3]{27-3\sqrt[3]9}<3$$
which is obvious.